# I'm getting "There was an error creating glob patterns, returning an empty array" error in NX monorepo

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have generated a lib (Angular component) but then decided to delete it, and removed all of its references. Also removed its path alias in `tsconfig.base.json` file, but now my Tailwindcss doesn't work and has broken my styles! I cannot serve my apps successfully anymore...

Here's the error I get:

```
> nx run angular-boilerplate:serve:development --open

| Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...
WARNING: There was an error creating glob patterns, returning an empty array
createGlobPatternsForDependencies: Error when generating globs.
ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'D:\p\2023\awesome\libs\shared\ui\popup'

| Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...
warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration
```

Angular works ok, everything is ok, because there's no problem with my codes! But it seems that something behind the scenes is still refering my deleted old lib (`D:\p\2023\awesome\libs\shared\ui\popup`).

How can I get rid of that and fix my workspace again?
Thanks a lot.

This is my NX info:

```
- Local: v16.7.4
- Global: v16.7.4
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem! As this is the Tailwindcss config file:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    join(__dirname, 'src/**/!(*.stories|*.spec).{ts,html}'),
    ...createGlobPatternsForDependencies(__dirname),
  ],
  ...
};
```

It actually tries to read my app's dependencies... And I have actually moved the lib to another folder, but I have forgotten to change the lib's `project.json` file correctly. I had to point `"sourceRoot"` option to the new path, where the lib has been moved! So as I was pointing to the old path, Tailwindcss was yelling!
I could also use the move command `nx g @nx/angular:move --project lib-name --destination new/path`, but sometimes we rather to do stuff by hand, to learn even more! And that sometimes costs, but it worth :D